# *OSX/UNIX* Testing if a file is on a locally mounted drive vs. AFP/SMB mounted?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, applescript, filepath

I'm working on an app that automates multi-machine processing of a dataset.

From a master computer (192.168.1.2), the user picks a file/folder to be processed.
The exact filepath is then shared with all the slave computers on a LAN network.

As long as the file is on a local drive, everything is fine and the shared filepath looks like :

```
afp://192.168.1.2/Volumes/LOCAL_DRIVE/Projects/file.zip
```

But if the user picks a file stored on an AFP mounted drive (a NAS for example), I'm unable to retrieve a complete filepath.

---

So for I'm able to get the mounted filepath :

```
/Volumes/NAS/Documents/file.zip
```

And I can get a list of mounted drives :

```
mbp:~ myself$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/LOCAL_DRIVE (hfs, local, journaled)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
localhost:/ndtfxrIYDV1dU5kiwHMwAy on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
//AdminNas@NAS._afpovertcp._tcp.local/NAS on /Volumes/NAS (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by myself)
//AdminUser@Remote_MacPro._afpovertcp._tcp.local/DATA on /Volumes/DATA (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by myself)
```

I'm seeking help to parse theses infos to :

- test if a file is AFP-mounted or not
- if true, extract an URL
  (afp://NAS._afpovertcp._tcp.local/NAS/Documents/file.zip)

Any clues ?

+Bonus point : retrieve the IP adress of the network volume !

Comment: Possibly a roll your own version of, "stat -f --format=%t /path" might be an option. It provides a filesystem type.  You might be able to use that to determine locality without the need for looking at the mounted drive list.

Comment: Thanks! Best I could do with `stat` is extracting the mysterious "device number". Example :
`mbp:~ myself$ stat -f "%d" /Volumes/NAS` gives me
`771751941`. Still I can't figure a way to reverse engineer the volume+AFP address :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/statfs)

You should be able to work something out from the following (untested).

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  struct statfs buf;
  if (statvfs("/tmp", &buf) == 0){
    printf("filesystem typeid: %d\n", buf.f_type);
    printf("filesystem type: %s\n", buf.f_fstypename);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Presumably, if it's not a local filesystem it won't be HFS.

Comment: Unfortunately that's using Xcode library, which won't be available on standard client machines. (I can't even test right now cause it's not installed on my laptop, will try tomorrow)

Comment: Try it anyway, this is a common low level routine so should be there.  The link is to documentation that's part of the xcode docs.  The functionality should still exist by default.

Comment: Compiling echoes : `9: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint32_t’`. And running result is `filesystem typeid: 0   
filesystem type: `, whatever the input is. (Can't debug that because I'm a total noob in C I must admit)

Comment: change %ld to just %d to fix the warning.  I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: No more warning, but it's not working : `filesystem typeid: 0 filesystem type: ` all the time.

Comment: Beats me... I don't have a mac to test this on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

I managed to extract the mount point using `df`, then tested it against a list of AFP mounted volumes sourced with `mount`. The whole thing being cleaned and managed using `grep` and `awk`.
Was a good learning exercise.

So this allows to :
- test if the file is local or AFP-mounted (remote)
- deliver a filepath accordingly

```
#!bin/bash

## Input as arguments, only one file or folder, with absolute filepath including "/Volumes/..."


## Get a nice $AFP_list of AFP-mounted volumes
AFP_list=$(mount |grep "afpfs" |awk {'print $1'})

## Get $base_volume of our input file
base_volume=$(df -PH "$1" |grep "%" |awk {'print $1'})


## Check if $base_volume is part of $AFP_list
if grep -q "$base_volume" <(echo "$AFP_list"); then
## If TRUE, deliver the network volume filepath
    echo "afp:$base_volume"
## If FALSE, deliver the original filepath
else
    echo "$1"
fi
```